# After installing oh-my-zsh: ... /.zshrc:source:34: no such file or directory ... /.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just tried to install [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).  I get the following error when I try to run `rvm`:

```
zsh: command not found: rvm
```

I also get the following error when I try to open a new tab:

```
/Users/jack/.zshrc:source:34: no such file or directory: /Users/jack/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
/Users/jack/.zshrc:source:38: no such file or directory: .bashrc
```

Here's my `.zshrc` file:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git bundler brew gem rvm cscairns)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...

source .bashrc
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

What do I need to do to fix these errors?

Answer (score 25):

Installing `zsh` doesn't install Oh My Zsh, which might explain if you don't have an `oh-my-zsh.sh` file at all (this was the case for me).

You can install [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh) by running

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Comment: Two weeks of issues with zsh came to an end with this one line. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

For this:

`/Users/jack/.zshrc:source:34: no such file or directory: /Users/jack/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh`

The problem is this line:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

You don't have a file called `oh-my-zsh.sh` in `/Users/jack/.oh-my-zsh`

For this:

`/Users/jack/.zshrc:source:38: no such file or directory: .bashrc`

The problem is the same as above; essentially, you don't have `.bashrc` file in `/Users/jack/`

Your `$ZSH` is pointing to `/Users/jack/.oh-my-zsh` and it looks like there's no such file in that directory with the name `zsh.sh`

As far as the initial problem (`zsh: command not found: rvm`) the issue is that the command `rvm` is not located anywhere in your `$PATH` which apparently points to `/usr/local/bin` plus whatever the system-wide setting is.

I recommend you use `find / -name "rvm"` and see where in the file system is `rvm` really located and then update your $PATH variable as so: `export PATH=/path/to/rv/:$PATH`

Answer (score 4):

Quick fix to this issue

```
/Users/jack/.zshrc:source:34: no such file or directory: /Users/jack/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Make the executable, executable.

```
cd .oh-my-zsh/ && chmod 744 oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Then run `exec zsh` to restart your shell. If you don't get the error, and your selected theme is working, you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

whenever I opened a new terminal window (iterm2) I encountered the same problem:

```
/Users/XXX/.zshrc:source:129: no such file or directory: /oh-my-zsh.sh
```

after running `source .zshrc` everything loaded fine though.

I did however have a `oh-my-zsh.sh` in my `~/.oh-my-zsh` directory.

(it doesnt need to be altered with `chmod +x` or anything.)

I realised everything I was missing was the line `ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh` before the lines with

`export ZSH="/Users/XXX/.oh-my-zsh"`
 and `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I removed my old .oh-my-zsh file which was located in `home/username/.oh-my-zsh`
then installed it again by runnung `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`
And the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below line to your `~/.zshrc` file to fix the error with `rvm`

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error:

```
/Users/frankus/.zshrc:source:50: no such file or directory:  /Users/frankus/.oh-my-zsh^M/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

I fixed it by renaming the `oh-my-zsh` folder

```
mv ~/.oh-my-zsh^M ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and the error is occurring due to simple typo.

In your `.zshrc` file where you set the name of the theme don't include quotation marks.
So instead of doing

```
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
```

you should rdo the following

```
ZSH_THEME=robbyrussell
```

This will solve your problem of getting a error when opeing a new tabs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue turned out to be .zshrc file itself, as I've migrated to another machine and simply copied the complete file instead of changing value of `ZSH` which was set to `ZSH=<old_machine_path>/.oh-my-zsh` just changed it to newer machine
s path and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on MacOS and get an error similar to:

`/Users/USERNAME/.zshrc:78: no such file or directory: ^[]7;file://WHATEVER/Users/USERNAME^G`

make sure no quotation marks are around:

`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

in `~/.zshrc`.

I had ` around it.

Answer (score 0):

Move `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` after the PATH variable so it looks like below. Save and reopen Terminal.

```
export ZSH="/Users/<username>/.oh-my-zsh"
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$ZSH:$PATH
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```